# In the intereference in famous Young Double Slit Experiement isnt the wave pattern forming on the screen due to bending of waves only?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, double-slit-experiment

In the famous Double slit experiment the waves from a source hit two slits and then they get interference at the screen but isnt the interefernce along the screen due to bending of waves only ? Isnt "bending the reason" we are being able to observe the pattern along the whole plane? As otherwise only at centre something would be formed isnt if bending not happened ?  Or is there some other reason for pattern being formed all over the plane ? [ What i know wave form bends due to secondary wavelets being formed in the slits in case of a single slit diffraction , the bending is most probably the wave propagation line being turned to an angle when coming in contact with an obstacle and by definition that is called diffraction ]

Comment: You need to explain how bending has anything to do with diffraction. What bends? How does it bend? How does that produce diffraction?

Comment: Edited the problem statement

Comment: Which physical effect is 'bending'?

Comment: The far field of an Illuminated double slit has the familiar profile of the fourier transform of the slit system. The near field however looks quite different. I don't see how anything characterised as bending could be responsible.

Comment: The bending of light is not a new term but it makes more sense when you visualize photon trajectories bending or scattering around or off edges. When millions of photons scattered and defract around the edges of a double slit they will create an interference pattern when they reach the detection screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The 'bending' is part and parcel of the *diffraction* that occurs at each slit. Diffraction is the spreading out of waves: instead of the wavefronts remaining plane (but very diminished in extent) and propagating only in the one 'straight ahead' direction, the wavefronts emerging from the slits are slightly curved and propagate in a narrow fan of directions. So waves from the two slits overlap on the screen and interfere.

Recommendation: read up about *Diffraction*.

Comment: So Sir why dont we say a word about diffraction in case of normal YDSE ? As bending means its diffraction taking place isnt Sir ?

Comment: But also one thing Sir diffraction only takes place when wavelength is comprabale to slit widths but in normal YDSE slith are not comparable at all , so why bending is occuring in normal YDSE?

Comment: This does not answer the question. How does bending have anthing to do with producing diffraction?

Comment: @Orion_Pax The main diffracted beam spreads through a semi-angle $\theta$ given by $\sin\theta=\frac{\lambda}b$ in which $b$ is the slit width. So if $\lambda=5\times 10^{-7}$m and $b=1 \times 10^{-4}$m, then $\theta=0.28°=0.005$ rad. That means that the main beam from each slit will spread out over a 10 mm wide strip on a screen placed a metre from the double slit. That'll be wide enough for a few interference fringes if the slits are less than (say) 0.5 mm apart. [There are also weaker 'side lobe' to the diffracted beam]

Comment: @Dan The bending doesn't *produce* diffraction but is part of the phenomenon of diffraction. As the wavefronts become curved (instead of the plane incident wavefronts) we now get many propagation directions instead of one, because the propagation directions are at right angles to the wavefronts. So the original propagation direction (of the waves before they reach the slit) changes to many different directions. If that isn't bending, I don't know what is!

Comment: @Orion_Pax "diffraction only takes place when wavelength is comparable to slit widths" This statement is oversimplified, as I hope I showed in my previous comment.

Comment: I see some points which i get from your point Sir , the diffracted waves from both the slits gets interferenced and form a uniform distributed fringe pattern (fringe width of lambdaD/d) ? And why we consider only one wave path difference from each slit while calculating path difference ? Why dont we consider many wave lines interference as one do in case of single slit diffraction from each slit?  And Sir what do you mean by 'weaker side lobe '? Tell me if anything is incorrect please

Comment: And by your statement i think there is a bit difference between diffraction fringes and interference fringes ? And sir what is sintheta = 1.22lamdba/b then indicates?

Comment: (a) "the diffracted waves from both the slits [interfere] and form a uniform distributed fringe pattern (fringe width of lambdaD/d) ?" Yes, if 'width' means separation of centres of bright fringes. (b) "why we consider only one wave path difference from each slit while calculating path difference ? Why don't we consider many wave lines interference as one do in case of single slit diffraction from each slit?" Because the single slits are usually very narrow compared with their separation. This justifies our treating what happens at the double slit separately as interference and diffraction.

Comment: (c) Side lobes. This is textbook stuff. Please read up about single slit diffraction. (d) "there is a bit difference between diffraction fringes and interference fringes ?" Yes, the details of the patterns are different, but both patterns can be explained using the idea of interference. (e) "sintheta = 1.22lamdba/b" This gives the spread of the central maximum of the diffraction pattern due to a *circular* aperture.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for explaining though i have queries regarding points b and e , will ask if you have no problem . Although most i get it

Comment: @Philip Wood Sir may i ask?

Answer (score 1):

The classical explanation of how waves of light move is that the light spreads out in all directions from every point on the leading edge of the wave, but each of these spreading fans of light interferes with all the others, and the overall shape of the wave is a result of all that interference. So in terms of that picture, what happens when a wavefront hits a barrier with two slits is that the points along the wavefront that are next to the slits act as expanding fans of light as they usually do, but now the expanding fans of rest of the wavefront are blocked everywhere else by the barrier. Given that, the light expands from each of the slits without any interference from all the points along the rest of the wavefront. The only interference mechanism that remains is that the expanding light from one slit interfers with the expanding light from the other.

Comment: Sir you mean lets say a wave is passing through straight along x -axis , as it travels each point on that wave along that x -axis can be considered as a secondary point source and hence just a unidirectional wave can make the whole xyz coordinate space a zone where sound/light can be reached anywhere?

Comment: And the answer you said is valid for any size of source and distance of screen and stuff ? Like there is no such approximatiom of slit distances and other distances like wavelength ? It always happens ?

Comment: I"m not sure I understand your first comment.  But yes, it always happens.  Nature makes no approximations.  We do only to make the calculations easier.

Answer (score 0):

The classical term interference is what is taught in high school and 1st year university and it is a very old theory (100 years ago).... but there are more advanced theories because the "interference" explanation means that photons are cancelling which is a violation (not allowed) of conservation of energy. There are 2 famous scientists (Dirac and Feynman) any many others that stated that every photon determines its own path... and experiments were done with single photons and the "pattern" still emerges.  In the "pattern" there is no energy in the dark spots, the bright spots have all the photons.  In masters university in quantum optics they teach the Feynman path integral which is a theory that shows how a photon will take a preferred direction or path.  Old thinking is that the nothing happens before a photon is created but in reality an excited electron in the atom is already generating forces in the EM field before the photon is created.

Comment: I will take the phrase *advanced theories* to mean *more recent theories*, but not to mean *improved theories*.   Both the path-integral method and the method of the quantum theory of fields describe interference.